# Plotting results problem using Pspice

Tags: pspice, orcad

I am performing a simulation of an eletronic circuit using Pspice and OrCAD. I want to know how the circuit will behave for long periods of time (in this case, 500s). After the simulation this weird plot appears.[image]

I don't know if it is because of the settings of the simulation which are the following ones:
[image]

If someone knows what is wrong I would be very greatful.

Comment: The problem is there're only so many pixels on the screen. What is the operating frequency of your circuit?

Comment: Pixel aliasing.But it looks pretty steady

Comment: @ThePhoton It is 50Hz. I see, so is there a way to stretch the x axis or a similar method?

Comment: usually you can zoom in